# Print multiple PDF page ranges

Tags: pdf, automation, adobe

I have a PDF with 200+ editable pages and need to hardcode print to PDF them into smaller PDF files (ie page 1-2, 3-8, 9, 10-11, 12-14, etc..).

Is there a way to automate this since I do this exercise each month? Right now I have to manually print each sub section one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) to copy a range of pages from a PDF file to another.

For example, to write pages 3-8 from input.pdf to output.pdf you could run the following from the command prompt, using the [command line options](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm) to specify the first and last page to process.

```
gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=3 -dLastPage=8 -o output.pdf input.pdf
```